# What convergence tests to use here?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It seems that all the tests that I tried failed or I did not use them in a clever way:

> Is $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} (1-\dfrac {1}{\ln n})^n$ convergent?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the logarithmic test which states that:
If we have $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ a series with positive terms then

let $l=\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim}\frac{\text{ln}\frac{1}{a_n}}{\text{ln}(n)}$. If $l>1$ the series is convergent,if $l<1$ the series is divergent. For $l=1$ we can't conclude.

In your case,the limit is $\infty$,which means the series is convergent.

Comment: Value $l = - \infty$ is impossible for $a_n \in (0,1)$. There's probably a sign missing.

Comment: It's true,my bad. The answer is $\infty$,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$
\frac{n}{\log^2n} \to \infty 
\quad \text{and} \quad 
\left( 1 - \frac{1}{\log n} \right)^{\log n} \to 1/e,
$$ 
for large enough $n$ we have 
$$
\frac{n}{\log n} \ge \frac{2}{\log 2} \log n, 
\qquad
\left( 1 - \frac{1}{\log n} \right)^{\log n} \le 1/2. 
$$ 
Then 
$$
\left( 1 - \frac{1}{\log n} \right)^{n} = \left( \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\log n} \right)^{\log n} \right)^{\frac{n}{\log n}} \le \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{2}{\log 2} \log n} = \frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
By comparison, our series is convergent.